# These factor groups are isomorphic to which group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I am asking a question from Abstract Algebra Assignment in which I am having a trouble.

> Let $$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a^{-1} \end{pmatrix}: a,b\in\mathbb{R} , a>0\right\}$$ and $$N=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}: b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$ Then which of the following are true?
>
> 1. $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ under addition.
> 2. $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\{a \in\mathbb{R}: a>0\}$ under multiplication.
> 3. There is a proper normal subgroup $N'$ of $G$ which properly contains $N$.

For option 1,2 I am really confused what $G/N$ will look like although I know that now multiplication and addition will be Mod $N$. So, I would really like to work out 1,2 myself if one can just tell me structure of $G/N$.

For Option 3, I need complete guidance as I have no clue for this.

I shall be really thankful for your help.

Comment: Hint, what does it mean for $G_1G_2^{-1} \in N$? This is a good place to start. This will tell you what the cosets are.

Comment: are you sure that must have $a>0$?

Comment: As demonstrated below, $a>0$ does give an isomorphism that helps answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Bbb R^*$ be a set $\{a \in\mathbb{R}: a>0\}$. It is easy to check that $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot )$ is a group and a map $f:(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)\to (\Bbb R,+)$, $x\mapsto \log(x)$ is an isomorphism of groups. So (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Now, as lhf [pointed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3788487/71850), consider a map $h: G\to \Bbb R^*$, $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ 0&a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \mapsto a$. An equality $$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\ 0 & a_1^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2\\ 0 & a_2^{-1} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2 & a_1b_2+a_2^{-1}b_1\\ 0 & a_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$ valid for all $a_1, a_2\in \Bbb R^*$ and $b_1, b_2\in \Bbb R$ shows that $h$ is a surjective homomorphism from $(G,\cdot)$ to $\mathbb (\Bbb R^*,\cdot)$. Clearly, $\ker h=N$. Thus we proved (2).

To show (3), it suffices to pick an arbitrary proper normal subgroup $H’$ of $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)$ which properly contains $1$ (for instance, $H’=\{e^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$) and put $N’=h^{-1}(H')$.

Comment: @SebastianSpindler Thanks for your corrections and sorry for the misprints.

Comment: I couldn't take a look at your answer now as I am in middle of my End Term Exams. But I am giving you bounty points. Can you please answer when I will ask my questions ( if any) in your answer later in comments?

Comment: @User Thanks. I'll try to answer your possible questions. Good luck with the exams.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Prove that $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ 0&a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \mapsto a$ is a surjective homomorphism $G \to \mathbb R^*_+$ with kernel $N$. Then compose with an isomorphism $\mathbb R^*_+ \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm doing this problem just for further practice with groups, and using your hint I was able to prove the first two, #1 using the first isomorphism theorem, then #2 by constructing that isomorphism and then using transitivity, but I'm still stuck on #3.

Comment: @JnPS, the subgroups of $G/N$ correspond to the subgroups of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @lhf can you please tell an isomorphism from $ \mathbb{R}_{+}^*→\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @lhf also it would be really kind of you if you can  add some more details to your answer .

Comment: @User, what common function you know that satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$?